# How to get an access to a view and test if view is visible?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, android-testing, robolectric

I got fragment and got if/else condition. Based on this condition textView visibility VISIBLE / GONE.
How in robolectric test mock or get an access to that textView and check the visibility ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robolectric is used as an alternative to launch the app in the emulator, you'll want to use espresso to test what state the view is in.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MyUnitTest {

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        // Launch activity or fragment
    }

    @Test
    fun 'view is visble'() {
        // when viewmodel is visible 

        // then, Espresso
        onView(withId(R.id.MyViewId))
            .check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE)))
    } 

    @Test
    fun 'view is gone'() {
        // then, Espresso
        onView(withId(R.id.MyViewId))
            .check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.GONE)))
    } 
}
```

https://android.github.io/android-test/downloads/espresso-cheat-sheet-2.1.0.pdf